# Fraction in brackets

Tags: fractions

I want to have a fraction in brackets. Something like:
`$${\log C \brack \log 2}$$`, but with the line in the middle. I know this possibility: `$$\left[\frac{\log C}{\log 2}\right]$$`. Nonetheless, does something easier exist?

Comment: What do you mean by easier, because this is already pretty simple and I am not sure you'll find something really shorter to produce what you want.

Comment: You could use a graphical interface like LatexIt (http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php?lang=en) to produce your formulae if you do not like typing the code verbatim, but in the end the same code will be produced. Side note: do not use `$$` to delimit display math environments unless you are using plain TeX -- use `\[` and `\]` or `\begin{equation}` `\end{equation` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most simple way to produce what you want without using a graphical interface. As mentioned by @ach in the comments, you should replace the `$$` by `\[` and `\]` or `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`.

Comment: Well actually, it's not the most simple way (see my answer:-) But you just shouldn't use such an interface in LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using LaTeX, first of all get rid of `$$` and prefer the construction `\[...\]`.

Then load `amsmath`, if you plan to do math in your document. Then define

```
\newcommand{\fbrack}[2]{\genfrac{[}{]}{}{}{#1}{#2}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\fbrack}[2]{\genfrac{[}{]}{}{}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\[
\fbrack{\log C}{\log 2}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Syntax of `\genfrac`:

```
\genfrac{<left delimiter>}{<right delimiter}{<thickness>}
        {<style declaration>}{<numerator>}{<denominator>}
```

If `<left delimiter>` and `<right delimiter>` are empty, no delimiter is printed; if `<thickness>` is empty, the fraction line is drawn with the default thickness; otherwise it should be a dimension.

If `<style declaration>` is empty, then the generalized fraction will respect the current math style; otherwise it can be

- `0` to mean that `\displaystyle` must be used
- `1` to mean that `\textstyle` must be used
- `2` to mean that `\scriptstyle` must be used
- `3` to mean that `\scriptscriptstyle` must be used

For instance, `\binom` is defined by `amsmath` by

```
\newcommand{\binom}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}}
```

while `\dbinom` is

```
\newcommand{\dbinom}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{0pt}{0}{#1}{#2}}
```

Using a foreign syntax such as `{A\brack B}` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\def\brack{\overwithdelims[]}

$${\log C \brack \log 2}$$

\bye
```

(Plain TeX)